# Copy Symfony entity from one connection to another / Store entity in session for live interaction

Tags: php, session, doctrine, symfony

I am working on a Symfony project. The project is about generating worksheets and gives users the features to edit all aspects of a worksheet. For example questions, text, variables and system is able to return a worksheet with all answers and explanations. The system is able to generate random worksheets.

So I have created several entities in Symfony. Starting with a Wordsheet as the base. So a Worksheet has questions, questions have answers, variables (changeable by the user) and child questions, etc and answers have explanations.

```
Worksheet->Questions
    Question->Answers
    Question->ChildQuestions
    Question->Variables
        Answer->Explanation
```

That is the basic structure but there are several other deep relationships. Each worksheet comes with a service that processes it. And a basic default/prototype of the worksheet is stored in the database and loaded when the user visits the worksheet page. I am trying to create a system where I can mount a worksheet on a session so that the user can interact with it via Ajax/AngularJS/API.

**My Solutions**

The first solution I thought was store a worksheet entity into a session with all it's relationships. But this is almost impossible because of PHP deep copy issue when using clone. I also hate the idea of serializing the worksheet entity due to it's complexity.

The second solution was to create a second Smyfony connection and simply clone the worksheet entity to the other connection/database with the session id. I have been successfully able to clone the entity with all it's relationship to the second connection/database but when I access the entity a second time all relationships mappings are lost although I see very identical data from the first database in the second database but all relationships have been lost. i.e when I use Worksheets->GetQuestions() I get an empty array although the data is there in the database.

Here is my Symfony doctrine multiple connections setup;

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types:
                  enum: string
            session:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host2%'
                port:     '%database_port2%'
                dbname:   '%database_name2%'
                user:     '%database_user2%'
                password: '%database_password2%'
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: session
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection:     default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: ~
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true
            session:
                connection: session
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: ~
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true
```

I have had lots of problems with this setup working through it. Although now the data is correctly saved to the second connection/database. For example I can't have auto_mapping: true for more than 2 connections, I think this would have solved my relationships problem. In symfony I use code like this to clone the entity to the second connection/database;

```
$WorksheetClone = $RendererService->GetProcessedCopy ();
$WorksheetClone->setGUID($WorksheetClone->getGUID().'.'.$worksheet_session_key);
$WorksheetClone->setName($WorksheetClone->getName().'.'.$worksheet_session_key);
$WorksheetClone->setSessionReference($worksheet_session_key);

$session_em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('session');
$session_em->persist($WorksheetClone);
$session_em->flush();
```

I am looking for a solution to save the worksheet somehow maybe through sessions or database so that the user can interact with it via API. I welcome any solutions or help with my solutions. Thanks.